# Process not running correctly

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I'm trying to run a shell process that creates a file, but no file is created. But my output lines look great, however!

```
String s = "openssl x509 -inform pem -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem > pubkey.pem";
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);
    System.out.println("public key extracted");
} catch (IOException e1) {System.out.println("IOException");
} catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Exception");
}
```

The funny thing is that when I copy that string off of the console and paste it into a terminal, this works perfectly. I've used this exact shell approach for other OpenSSL commands, and it works fine. Very confused about why this isn't working.

If you aren't sure about what is supposed to happen here, there is an x509 file called `cert.pem` on the disk. This command reads that file, extracts the public key from it, and puts that key in a file called `pubkey.pem`. But at the end of this, I have no file called `pubkey.pem`. Like I said, if I put that exact line in a terminal command prompt, the file is created perfectly.

Thanks for any advice.

EDIT: I should also mention that I printed out the current directory, so I know that isn't the issue.

Comment: Print out the "current directory" (`System.getProperty("user.dir")`) to ensure you're running where you think you are.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I verified that I am running in the correct directory.

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.